# What do you call the small tube with ink in a pen?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, image-identification

[image]

What would you say in everyday life if you wanted to buy them?

We need to buy some ______.

1. pen ink holders
2. ink reservoirs
3. pen shanks
4. pen rods
5. small tubes with ink?

Comment: It looks like magic, the pen seems to be floating in midair! But I'm guessing it's lying on a glass top table, neat illusion though. PS When the ink dries up, it's "time to buy a new pen".

Comment: http://kids.britannica.com/comptons/art-53777/Cross-section-of-a-ballpoint-pen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to howstuffworks.com, [*How Ballpoint Pens Work*](http://home.howstuffworks.com/pen3.htm), it is called an *ink resevoir*:

> The ball rotates freely and rolls out the ink as it is continuously fed from the **ink reservoir** (usually a narrow plastic tube filled with ink).

However, in a context where you need to buy more and you're at the store, I think that you should ask for *pen refills*. From [Office Depot](http://www.officedepot.com/a/browse/pen-refills/N=5+4551/):

[image]

Comment: +1 for *refills*. You might also mention *ink cartridges*, which is the more common term for fountain pens as opposed to ball point pens.

Comment: "ink reservoir" is the functional name for it's purpose.  Any container or cavity inside a pen that holds ink is the ink reservoir.  In non-refillable pens, the reservoir is a cavity in the pen body.  A replaceable tube of ink is typically called a "refill" when it includes the writing tip, or an ink "cartridge" if it contains only ink.